# With the following settings shown here, will there be any caching in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, http, browser-cache

> browser.cache.disk.enable = false
>   browser.cache.memory.enable = false
>   network.http.use-cache = **true**

With the following settings above, will there be any caching in FF?

Does the `disk.enable` and `memory.enable` set to `false` override the true setting  of `use-cache`?

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.use-cache

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the disk.enable and memory.enable set to false override the true setting of use-cache?

From the mozillaZine link, this would be a reasonable assumption. "This [use-cache] preference controls whether to cache files ... either in memory or on disk." - and if neither memory or disk caching is enabled (as implied by the other two settings) then it would be reasonable to assume the page cannot be cached.